# SP Online : Flow - for selected file - copy that file - link for a new file

Tags: sharepoint-online, flow

I have flow that triggers for selected file.

I am able to copy that file but I want to send link to this file. I have problem with "get item" because i dont have ID of the new file.

Is there a way to get link for the copied file or at least file directory?

Thanks for ideas!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the ID from the Library item dynamically if you are using a Workflow. It works the same way that list items do. For example, if I have a List or Library with a Workflow that say, sends an email to a user, and I want to put a link to the specific item, I will want to craft a link similar to this:

```
<a href="http://site/subsite/Library/DispForm.aspx?ID=[ID]">Link Text</a>
```

The [ID] part can be inserted into the link via the text builder, like shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Since you are wanting the ID of the NEW file, create a Workflow on the NEW library that triggers when a new item is added, and get the ID from that item. I hope this helps!

Comment: I cant make flow for every directory to send email and get a link. I need to send the link when i trigger the flow and copy the file.

Comment: Ahh, I apologize. I had assumed that all of the copies were going to a single Library.

Comment: its fine. I am currently using solution "example.sharepoint.com/sites/project/folder1/folder?web=1" it works for me just fine same for documents "example.sharepoint.com/sites/project/folder1/folder/doc.docx?web=1"

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad you found a solution!